# Interstitial between SplashScreen and HomePage (Segue not working, blackscreen)

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, splash-screen, interstitial

I know this is a frequently asked question, but I didn't find my answer after reading all the similar questions.

So here is my issue, I am integrating Ads in my application, and basically what I'm trying to achieve is to show an `Interstitial` during the `SplashScreen`, just before accessing the `HomePage`.

For now this is what I have :

**- Launch the App -> Display the SplashScreen -> Display the HomePage and right after Display the Interstitial.**

What I want :

**- Launch the App -> Display the SplashScreen -> Display the Interstitial and when the Ad is closed, Display the HomePage.**

I can display the `Interstitial` during the `SplashScreen`, but my `performSegueWithIdentifier` is not working, either it shows me a Blackscreen or the App blocks on the Splas`enter code here`hScreen.

To illustrate what I'm saying, here is some code of my `SplashScreen` `ViewController`.

```
- (void)loadHomeView
{
    if(_isDataLoaded && !_isInterstitialDisplay && [MFPreferencesUtils firstLaunch] != nil)
    {
        [self createSplashInterstitial];
        //I also tried with performSelectorOnMainThread
    }
}
```

The Interstitial Delegate :

```
-(void)adsAdapterInterstitialDisappear:(Adapter *)adsAdapter{
   _isInterstitialDisplay = NO;
   [self displayHome];
}
```

And the displayHome method, called when the user closes the Ad :

```
-(void) displayHome
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SplashscreenDisappearToHome" sender:self];
    });
}
```

I think this is a simple behaviour, maybe I don't really understand how Segues work, but if I don't call the `Interstitial` and instead, directly call my `HomePage` it is working.

```
- (void)loadHomeView
{
    if(_isDataLoaded && !_isInterstitialDisplay && [MFPreferencesUtils firstLaunch] != nil)
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displayHome) withObject:nil
    waitUntilDone:NO];
    }
}
```

Thank you for reading, let me know if you have some advices.

Comment: As far as I can remember, you can't really control interstitial lifecycle as it is treated like a modal. I have code that does exactly what you want to achieve, but don't have access to it right now. What I would suggest you to do would be: Create a home screen that mimics your splash screen; 
From there, call your interstitial; Listen to interstitial closed callback to perform segue to the next screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I was able to fix it by calling my method in viewDidAppear. This was a call to performSegue when my View wasn't loaded yet because of the Interstitial.